# Display none in JQuery not working

Tags: jquery, html

Show element works fine, however nothing happens when trying to hide same element.

HTML after showing element:

```js
$(".container").click(function() {
  $('.top-menu').css('display', 'block');
});

$("div.container.change").click(function() {
  $('.top-menu').css('display', 'none');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container change" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <nav class="top-menu" style="display: block;">
    enter code here
```

Really looks to be basic as hell, but I do not see why it's not working. Thanks for reviewing.

Comment: You have “.div” in one of the selectors, should just be “div”

Comment: Oh yeah, changed that, but still not working.

Comment: Looks like it works to me: https://jsfiddle.net/9p7z5rbe/1/  (though note the `.container.change` element will trigger both  handlers, which may be the issue, if you don't have the functions in the same order in your code.)

Comment: It seems you are executing both the functions (hide and show). ".container" and ".div.container.change" selectors are referring to same object. So, both the event functions will get executed (the order in which they are defined).

Comment: So what's the workaround?

Comment: Just use one event function and toggle property

`$(".container").click(function() {
  $('.top-menu').toggle();
});`

Comment: @gagan That worked perfectly, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Just bind the click handler to the container element (see below) and remove the inline `onclick` attribute. You can use `.hide` and `.show` as a shorthand for `.css('display', 'none')` and `.css('display', 'block')`.

If you need to toggle the display then use `.toggle` on the menu element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // ref container
  var container = $('.container'),
      // cache the menu selector
      menu = $('.top-menu');

  container.on('click', function(){
    menu.hide(); 
  });  
});

// you can use menu.toggle(); to show/hide on container click
```

```css
.container {
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.top-menu {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <nav class="top-menu">
    Enter code here
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

REMOVE THE ONLICK FUNCTION THAT YOU CALL ON THE HTML.It will work.

```js
$(".container").click(function() {
  $('.top-menu').css('display', 'block');
});

$("div.container.change").on('click',function() {
  $('.top-menu').css('display', 'none');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container change">
  <nav class="top-menu" style="display: block;">
    enter code here
  </nav>

</div>
```

Comment: The onclick attribute would have no effect on the other functions being asked about here.

Comment: @DanielBeck then what about the error you are receiving on console when you click on the element. It clearly says  `Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined`. When I remove it worked as expected. What is the issue with that?

Comment: I am getting error as well when I remove function it works cuz funct is not defined

Comment: @ŽeniaBogdasic Run the snippet in the question and click on the element. You will see the error

Comment: @ŽeniaBogdasic If you want to keep the `onclick function`,implement it in js. It won't be problem. But undefined method calls in js will definitely give you an error

Comment: I was assuming that that function would have been defined elsewhere and was unrelated to this question, but you're probably right that that's not a safe assumption, sorry.